# Count the number of each value in every variable, and summarise it in a new data frame in R

Tags: r, count

I am relatively new to R, and am trying to count the number of each value for each variable, in my whole data frame, where this would all be summarised into a new data frame. For example, my data looks like this:

```
cluster <- data.frame(sex = c(1,1,1,1,0),
                      mut = c(0,0,0,0,0),
                      ht = c(1,1,0,1,0),
                      wt = c(0,1,1,0,1),
                      group = c(1,0,0,0,0))
cluster

sex mut ht wt group  
1    0   1  0  1      
1    0   1  1  0         
1    0   0  1  0    
1    0   1  0  0
0    0   0  1  0
```

And I want to count how many 1's vs 0's of each variable there is, for the whole data frame.
My desired output is:

```
      Zeroes  Ones
sex    1       4
mut    5       0
ht     2       3
wt     2       3
group  4       1
```

I know how to do this for each variable individually through a variety of means, for example:

```
>table(cluster$sex) 
0   1
1   4
```

but I have 32 variables in each of 6 data frames so a quicker way to summarise this would be very helpful. I am thinking some sort of looping function, although I am not very knowledgeable in those. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a function by column using `apply`:

```
df <- apply(cluster, 2, function(x) c('one' = sum(x == 1), 'zero' = sum(x == 0)))
df <- data.frame(t(df)) # Rotate it so categories are rows
df
      one zero
sex     4    1
mut     0    5
ht      3    2
wt      3    2
group   1    4
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, you just save me hours of time :)

Answer (score 0):

`stack` with `table` (PS: convert to data.frame `as.data.frame.matrix`)

```
with(stack(df),table(ind,values))


      0 1
group 4 1
ht    2 3
mut   5 0
sex   1 4
wt    2 3
```